# Is it possible to pass parameters to jQuery .on handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to update a page with an AJAX call, where the user can pass some params into input fields, and then 'onclick' data is retrieved from a DB and the page is updated.

So essentially I'd like to pass the values a user has entered into certain fields to a jQuery .on(click) event.

These can then be consumed by the route handler so that the results that are displayed from the database are filtered by the user's input.

Current set up is below - How do we pass input field data on the button click?

**In functions.js:**

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        alert('Your parameters are :'+ $(this).data('value'));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/orders',
            success: function(result) {
                var html = '';
                for (var i = 0; i< result.length; i++) {
                    html += '<h2>' + result[i].id + ' ' + result[i].product + '</h2>';
                }
                $('#target').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**In ajax.ejs:**

```
<body>
      <h1>Ajax</h1>
      <input type="text" form="myform" />
      <button form="myform" >Get Orders</button>

        <div id="target">
        </div>

  </body>
```

**in orders.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    orders: function(req, res){
        db.query('select * from orders', function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.send(result)
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused with your question.  Why not put a class or id on the input and simply look it up and get it's value in the click event handler?  I'm not sure why you need to pass it on the event.

Comment: I need to pass a few params - E.g., {name:'test', number: 'test2'}. These are values that a user has entered into fields on the page. It needs to be passed on the event as they are dynamic and only at the time of the event have meaning.

Comment: Again, why can you not lookup those values in the click event handler?

Comment: Maybe I can :) New to this. What would the HTML / script look like please?

Comment: first would be easier if you show your current HTML, then we can adjust it and use the JS to get the values inside the event handler

Comment: Just like you are doing `$('button')` to select the button element by it's **tagName**, you can similarly select the other elements you need inside the event handler with selectors that identify them.  Then it is (typically) as simple as calling `.val()` on them to get their current values.

Comment: @CalvinNunesHTML is simple as: <body>
      <h1>Ajax</h1>
      <input type="text">
      <button form="myform" >Get Orders</button>

        <div id="target">
        </div>

  </body>

Comment: Side note to the topic though, it is possible to provide extra arguments to the `on` event handler using the `data` option of the method.  https://api.jquery.com/on/  But again, I haven't seen anything here that suggests your use case warrents that usage.

Comment: @Taplar Avgain, I'm fairly new to this - However your comments have solved this for me. Can I give you credit somehow?

Comment: Nah, you're good.  I've just pointed you towards ideas.  I didn't give you a solution.  Feel free to post the solution you came to.  S.O. does not discourage posters from providing their own solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "... essentially i'd like to pass the values a user has entered into certain fields to a jQuery .on(click) event."

Ok, the way to capture some user input with jQuery would be like this:

```
var input = $(<element-selector>).val();
```

You can use that code within the event handling function like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function (e) {
    var input = $(<element-selector>).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/orders?param=' + input,
        success: function(result) {
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 0; i< result.length; i++) {
                html += '<h2>' + result[i].id + ' ' + result[i].product + '</h2>';
            }
            $('#target').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

As you have a GET type of request, you may pass the data appended in the query string, as you see in the `url` param definition.

Comment: Thank you I just rounded this off with help from @Taplar but essentially just have you have answered. Great community, thanks all.